# Light a cigar in 100% O2 - what happens?

Tags: artemis

Weir's new novel *Artemis: A Novel* just arrived on my kindle.

Chapter 1: A rich guy lights a cigar, with an apparently ordinary lighter, in a 100% O<sub>2</sub> atmosphere and

> he enjoys it.

Why

> doesn't he and everyone in the room instantly burn to a crisp?

The atmosphere pressure is only 20% of Earth's, that can't be the reason, can it?

Comment: At 20% atmospheric pressure, the partial pressure of O2 would be equal to here on Earth (where it makes up 21% of the atmosphere).  How that affects things burning... perhaps you'd best ask over at Chemistry Stack Exchange.  Obviously anything that uses other atmospheric gases as catalyst would be affected, but that shouldn't come into play in your scenario.  On the other hand, the expansion of flame products ought to be quite different in a low pressure atmosphere.

Comment: The problem with Apollo 1 was twofold: it was 100% pure oxygen and **also** it was pressurized above one atmosphere to prevent any outside air from leaking in. The high pressure was an important factor in the fact that the fire burned hot enough to weld metals together. And even then it wasn’t instant, it was just fast and since the hatch opened inward it was impossible to open against the interior pressure in time to rescue the crew. You might take this line of questioning over to the physics Stack.

Answer (score 4):

Fire is the result of an oxidation reaction. It requires heat, fuel, and an oxidizer (usually oxygen). So oxygen itself does not burn.

If a fire would otherwise be oxygen-limited, then yes, the atmosphere content will matter quite a bit. But if the fire is fuel-limited, you can add all the oxidizer you want, and it won't affect the spread of the fire much. I think the cigar should burn normally.

The lighter might behave differently, since it's actually mixing fuel and air in a particular ratio. But the difference might not be much, since there's no leftover fuel in a normal atmosphere anyway.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are clearly off-topic. It only encourages people to ask them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are absolutely correct. They would all be burnt to a crisp ([source](https://sciencing.com/pure-o2-flammable-7804267.html)).

Comment: The Apollo astronauts on the moon missions used 100% Oxygen atmosphere and didn't suffer oxygen poisoning.  https://www.popsci.com/why-did-nasa-still-use-pure-oxygen-after-apollo-1-fire

Comment: But the Apollo 1 astronauts were killed when a spark from a wire set every thing even remotely combustible ablaze.

Comment: I thought the oxygen poisoning was a cool bonus but am not 100% sure on how that changes with pressure so I have removed that part and just left the base answer. Any research or links to how toxicity is effected by pressure would still be helpful to the answer

Comment: From what I've read, oxygen poisoning occurs only if the air pressure is much higher than natural 1 atmosphere (hence it is a serious concern for divers)

Comment: not even a concern for sport divers or advanced sport divers - nitrogen build up and then dispersal is a bigger concern - aka the bends, which happens with too fast decompression OR too long at depth and then total decompression.  Which is why decompression stops are usually at 20-ish feet, less than 1atm additional pressure, so you aren't absorbing more.  Mixed gas diving (helium/oxygen mix) fixes this - no nitrogen!  O2 poisoning becomes an issue with standard earth air at (IIRC) 12+ ATM (400ish feet) but other dangers like nitrogen narcosis kick it much shallower - 90-110 feet.

Comment: oxygen toxicity is definitely related to partial presssure (the first step in transport is uptake into the blood, after than the total atmospheric pressure doesn't matter)

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are clearly off-topic. It only encourages people to ask them

Comment: The reason the Apollo program got away with pure oxygen is because without gravity C02 produced by a fire will put the fire out. On Earth with gravity, the hot C02 will rise and the oxygen will continue to fuel the fire. I don't have a good explanation for why this was missed before the plugs out test during the program which killed the three astronauts. Lastly, I know this comment is late and related to an off-topic question, but maybe my comment will be edifying for someone in the comment section.